# Why do I see a frequency shift from center when transmitting a QPSK via USRP with GNU Radio?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, modulation, gnuradio, qpsk, software-defined-radio

I am transmitting a QPSK signal via GRC and when I look at it on the spectrum analyzer, the signal is shifted away from my center frequency. This shift increases the higher the center frequency (i.e. 1 MHz = almost no shift, 10 MHz = 1kHz shift, 50 kHz = 2.3kHz shift, 900 MHz = 43.5 kHz shift). Why does this shift occur? I have attached my flowgraph screenshot below. [image]

Comment: The most likely cause is that the USRP and the SA don't completely agree on what "one second" is.

Comment: also, PSK Mod is deprecated. Don't use it. It's mostly broken.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Is there another option to use?

Comment: Since you're starting a new thing here, definitely use GNU Radio 3.8 or 3.9 instead of 3.7. The digital blocks are undergoing changes, and I really don't think it pays to support the 3.7 way of doing things, now that nobody's going to use that.

Comment: In 3.8 and later, there's nice examples in the examples/digital subfolder. Orient on these.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Unfortunately I have to use 3.7 in this use case but I will be sure to check that out still for later applications, thanks!

Comment: @lceans then I can't help you. I **really** haven't heard of a good reason to stick with a piece of deprecated software if the next version of the very same software works flawlessly on the same platforms. So, whoever is defining that requirement to use 3.7 should definitely tell you the justification for that, and then I can help you solve the problem binding you to 3.7. I'm not kidding – 3.7 is in legacy-mode, and we're at best hoping to fix bugs now. Someone building new software based on it now is basically doomed to reimplement things very soon.

Comment: @lceans 90% of reasons I heard was "3.7 was hard enough to install, I don't know how to upgrade!" and that argument doesn't fly, installing GNU Radio is basically one or two lines that you can copy and paste from the installation guides these days.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are answers in the comments, but I am just going to put it down here.
Most probably the Local Oscilators (LOs) of your USRP and the Analyzer are not tuned/synchronized.
You could try to provide a common, external clock signal source to both of these devices.